# Object with unknown values in sinon mock withArgs - sinon.match

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, unit-testing, sinon

I am trying to create a unit test to test that an object that my code has created is successfully sent to an update function (not testing the update function currently as that would be an integration test).

What I am trying to do is use a sinon mock to check that the input to the update method is correct:

```
var objectToUpdate = {
    "_id": 55f019a32f55b4508b05a155,  //mongodb _id assigned earlier in the code
    etc...
}

var mock = sinon.mock(MyClass.prototype);
mock.expects("update").once().withArgs([objectToUpdate]);
otherClass.functionThatCallsUpdate(function(error, result){
  (typeof error).should.equal.null;
  mock.verify();
  mock.restore();
  done();
});
```

The problem is that the code I am testing is a part of the database population code, so I do not know what the _id of the object will be before the test is run as it is created earlier in the process, so the `withArgs()` part of the test is failing.

Is it possible to specify a partial object for `withArgs()` in a sinon mock, or is there another approach I should use?

A less useful (but better than nothing) option would be to be able to specify an expectation for the size of the array containing `objectToUpdate`, but I can't find a way to do that either.

Comment: If I understtod you correctly, you need to mock the `_id` of the object?

Comment: I am mocking the `update` method. I need the test to pass with any value of `_id`

Comment: Ok, and what error do you get?

Comment: No error, my test is just failing because the `_id`s don't match

Comment: Try `"_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId()`

Comment: Ok, than `"_id": new ObjectID()`.

Comment: That creates a new objectID which doesn't match to the one created in the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89173/discussion-between-lazarev-alexandr-and-carasel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to make this work by removing the _id from the object and using [sinon.match](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#sinon-match-api):

```
mock.expects("update").once().withArgs([sinon.match(objectToUpdate)]).yields(null);
```